# cant run expo project again

Tags: react-native, expo

Please I experienced an error trying to run my React Native Expo project that was working fine and in just 24hrs I tried to running the same project with "npx expo start" as usual to continue development and i got the following error:

```
D:\project\node_modules\ssri\lib\index.js:18
class IntegrityStream extends Minipass {
                              ^

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\project\node_modules\ssri\lib\index.js:18:31)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1287:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\project\node_modules\cacache\lib\entry-index.js:14:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1287:10)

Node.js v20.5.0
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\project
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c expo start -c

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\l9\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-13T15_43_11_109Z-debug.log
```

Expo Version : 0.7.1
React: 18.2.0,
React-Native: 0.71.8

I don't know what this error could be.